# Comparing 2 regression models

Tags: regression, stata, r-squared, method-comparison

I have 2 continuous outcome (independent) variables, A and B, and 1 dependent variable (biomarker) that are all very correlated. I would like compare the outcome variables in relation to the biomarker and assess whether the biomarker is able to explain more of A or of B.

Is there a way to statistically compare the Rsqr values of the 2 models for example?

I was also thinking of doing a wald test after a regression using the dependent variable as outcome and the 2 outcome variables as dependent variables; but the units of the outcome variables are different.

I work in STATA, R and SPSS, any type of code could really help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just directly compare the $R^2$s. If you want to see how sensitive the $R^2$s are to the amount of data selected you could do something like Mr. Masterov suggested above. My instict would be to randomly select 25% of the observations and fit models, making a vector of $R^2$s for each of your dep. vars.

Because I am so magnanimous, I've written you a little example. Should give you an idea of what I have in mind. Just tested in R, should work.

```
# Make some fake data 

N <- 100000 # our observation count

vBioMarker <- rnorm(N)

# Now let's make A and B from known generating processes 

# Note how I make the 'residual' for B have twice the variance of A
# this should make the 'true' R^2 different for the two

A <- 0.3 * vBioMarker + rnorm(N,0,1)

B <- 0.3 * vBioMarker + rnorm(N,0,2)

modelData <- data.frame(vBioMarker,A,B)


tempAMod <- lm(A~vBioMarker,data=modelData)

#check out the R^2
summary(tempAMod)$r.squared

# Now generate an estimated sampling dist of the R^2

#I'm going to use a loop here, it is slow, you could speed it up with
# on of the apply functions probably.

vRsqForA <- NULL

vRsqForB <- NULL

for(lSample in 1:10000){

  # make a vector with 25% of the obs numbers randomly selected

  vTempSubset <- sample(1:N,0.25*N)

  # fit the temp model for A

  tempModA <- lm(A~vBioMarker,
             data=modelData,
             subset=vTempSubset)

 # fit the temp model for B

  tempModB <- lm(B~vBioMarker,
             data=modelData,
             subset=vTempSubset)

 # Book the R^2s 

  vRsqForA <- c(vRsqForA,summary(tempModA)$r.squared)

  vRsqForB <- c(vRsqForB,summary(tempModB)$r.squared)


} # for each sample run

# some quick and dirty histograms, I suggest plotting both histograms on the 
# same graph using the methods in ggplot2, can't recall how to do that off 
# the top of my head

hist(vRsqForA,breaks=100)

hist(vRsqForB,breaks=100)
```

Comment: Thank you! Why would you choose 25% of the data instead of a bootstrapping method where you randomly sample N lines with replacement?

Comment: Yeah you could do that too. Nothing magical about 25%. This is where the art part of statistics comes in. I'd probably look at everything from 5%,10%,15%...25%.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to bootstrap the difference in $R^2$s from a Seemingly Unrelated Regression. This allows the errors associated with the 2 dependent variables to be correlated. Here's some Stata code using the cars dataset:

```
   sysuse auto, clear
   sureg (price weight) (mpg weight)
   bootstrap diff_R2 = (e(r2_2)-e(r2_1)), seed(123) reps(50):  sureg (price weight) (mpg weight)
```

This will get you output which looks like this:

```
Bootstrap results                               Number of obs      =        74
                                                Replications       =        50

      command:  sureg (price weight) (mpg weight)
      diff_R2:  e(r2_2)-e(r2_1)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |   Observed   Bootstrap                         Normal-based
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     diff_R2 |   .3614289   .0868189     4.16   0.000     .1912671    .5315908
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In this case, the $R^2$ from the mpg on weight regression is significantly higher than from price on weight.

On second thought, this may not be quite right. SUR uses asymptotically efficient, feasible, generalized least squares. The $R^2$ reported is the percent of variance explained by the predictors, though technically it is not a well-defined concept when GLS is used, which is presumably why Stata puts it in quotes in the output.