# How to compare 2 p-values?

Tags: regression, p-value, bootstrap, method-comparison

I have 2 continuous outcome (independent) variables, A and B, and 1 dependent variable (biomarker) that are all very correlated (i.e., p_A = 0.01, p_B= 0.000001). I would like compare the outcome variables in relation to the biomarker and assess whether the biomarker is able to explain more of A or of B. IS there a way to statistically compare these two models?

My instinct would be to use the bootstrap method to randomly draw 25% data from the entire dataset for 1000 times. For each time, we could fit the model A and B and obtain p_A and p_B. Then we could compute the difference  (p_A-p_B) and do the statistics based on the differences of 1000 draws.

Is this approach reasonable to compare the p-value? Is there any literature to support the p-value comparison (or other approaches)?

Comment: P-values are not the right thing to look at if you want to compare two models. The p-value is a random variable so it's not surprising that you're getting different p-values when fitting the same model to different data. You're reaching the same conclusion in both models, in any case. What question are you really trying to answer?

Comment: I want to compare two models which is better. If the p-value is useless for model comparison. Can I compare the R^2 from two different models?

Comment: Better *in which sense*?

Comment: I want to compare two models to see which could be more significantly correlated with independent variable, though both show significant correlations. For this reason, I'm thinking to use the bootstrap and compare the p-value difference (or maybe the R^2 difference) like this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140441/comparing-2-regression-models.

Comment: It sounds like you're fitting the _same_ model to different data. What is the purpose of your model?

Comment: Yes, I'm fitting the same model to different data. The motivation is to know if the model B (Y from new method results) could provide a significantly better correlation or not, though the model A (result from old methods) showed significant correlation as well.

Comment: It would help if you could edit your question and add more details about the transformation you've applied to `y` (or more details re: the different "methods"), the $R^2$ values from both models, scatter plots of `x` vs. `y1` and `x` vs. `y2`, plots of the residuals (e.g. fitted values vs. standardised residuals), etc. Remember, the more details you can give in the question the more likely it is that you'll find someone who can give an answer that is as relevant as possible.

Comment: You may find this useful -- [The Difference between "Significant" and "Not Significant" Is Not Itself Statistically Significant](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/000313006X152649); also see http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/signif4.pdf . It's best to focus on the underlying research question rather than on p-values.